# Is the AWS DynamoDB's free tier with 25 RCUs sufficient to read nearly 100Mb of data from 8 tables totally at any given instance?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I have text data on the DynamoDB's tables and there are 8 tables totally with max size of 256Kb - 300 Kb each. That makes 2Mb - 2.5Mb the total size of the DB.

I am reading the table from an app and I am making nearly 50 reads for all the tables from the app at any given instance of time. So that means at any given instance the total reads will be of size 100Mb

So will the 25 RCU's provided by the AWS DynamoDB's free tier be sufficient to carry out the above mentioned task, or will I be billed at the end of the month.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want eventually consisted read or strongly consistent reads? 50 requests per second is for one table only, or for each table?

Comment: I need 50 for each table and eventually consistent read

Comment: And do you need to read all the data in a single second? Or can this take a few seconds? Accessing 100 MB/second is quite a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need 50 for each table and eventually consistent read

Then you need 400 (50*8) eventually consistent (ES) reads per seconds. 1 RCU is 2 ES reads per second. Which means that performing 400 ES will require 200 RCU, resulting in being **way over your 25 RCUs**.

Subsequently, you will have to **pay for the excess RCUs** that you use.

Comment: Thank You for the clear answer.